# Bash: how to check if there is only one root id and all user UIDs are unique?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, rhel, audit

i have this bash script here that i'm trying to modify to check if there is only one root id, is it vulnerable and currently, this script only checks if there is a duplicate uid and display the users that shares the same uid. Thanks in advance! :)

**Bash Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/cat /etc/passwd| /bin/cut -f3 -d":" | /bin/sort -n | /usr/bin/uniq-c | while 
read x ; do
  [ -z "${x}" ] && break
  set -$x
  if [ $1 -gt1 ]; then
       users=`/bin/gawk -F: '($3 == n) { print $1 }' n=$2 /etc/passwd| /usr/bin/xargs`
       echo "Duplicate UID ($2): ${users}"
  fi
done
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Audit criteria: There is only one root id

Vulnerability: Yes

Details: See below


root:!:0:0::/:/usr/bin/bash

jdoe:*:0:1:John Doe:/home/jdoe:/usr/bin/bash
```

Comment: I suggest to replace `uniq-c` by `uniq -c` and please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Is there a reason you are using full paths for basic commands like `cut`, `grep`, `awk` etc?

Comment: @codeforester this was an example given to me and as im a beginner in bash scripting i didnt realised it until you pointed it out, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your script greatly because all you are looking for is user id 0, which is root:

```
#!/bin/bash
root_count=$(cut -f3 -d":" /etc/passwd | grep -wc 0)
if [[ $root_count > 1 ]]; then
  users=$(awk -F: '($3 == 0) { print $1 }' /etc/passwd | xargs)
  echo "Duplicate roots: ${users}"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to find that out:

```
if ! awk -F: '$3==0{c++}END{exit !(c<2)}' /etc/passwd ; then
    echo "More than one user with uid 0"
fi
```